# PHP: Join two files into one

Tags: php, file, executable, file-handling

there are two files one of which is a binary (a simple exe file). How can I use PHP to add some textual information to the end of this exe file (for example, from another text file)?

Any file manager seamlessly appends text to the end of the executable file, but is it possible to do using PHP?

UPDATE: Thanks a lot to @arkascha!

```
$file = 'original_file.exe';
$newfile = 'new_file.exe';
copy($file, $newfile);
$handle=fopen("new_file.exe", "a+"); 
fwrite($handle, "777777");
fclose($handle);
```

And we have a working exe file with the text "777777" at its end.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The executable file would then be unusable.

Comment: @Sietse Is that really true in all cases? I have no idea about MS-Windows, but I would expeect that there are executable files that won't get invalid just because of some additional text concatenated to them. For example script files. Or does `.exe` always mean 'binary', whatever binary is in that case?

Comment: The fact that I needed a suitable for using exe file - just add a few more bytes after EOF

Comment: @arkascha I think so, but even if it doesn't get corrupted; why would you want to do that? For what use? Can't you just put in a seperate file?

Comment: @Sietse You could for example use that space to add some sort of data container. All you have to do is read the own executable and extract it for usage. Bundling everything to a single files makes a lot of sense. Though as said: I have _no_ idea about MS-Windows systems. So this might also be absolutely without use :-)

Comment: Long story, but in a nutshell: one of my web services gives the user exe file that contains the XML (or INI, or something) with some settings that were made by this user. Thus, the user gets a unique exe (created on the basis of the reference file, of course) with its own parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is certainly possible, although I have no idea what that is meant to result in. All you have to do is open a file for writing, then open the first file for reading, read the content, write it into the file you have for writing and close the first file. Same with the second file. Last you close the file you opened for writing and have a new file that contains the concatenated content of both files. Why shouldn't that be possible?